# How to correctly speak to a shared element in css, javascript, html

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-transitions

A list with four items is displayed on my page. on hovering one of those, the background image is slightly moved. The tutorial i have now assigns the activeIndex (menu.dataset.activeIndex) of the div containing the four items an index number in a for each loop. now they are numbered 0-3 and i can console.log() this, they look like this:

```
<div id="menu" data-active-index="3"></div>
```

each one is supposed to set the background to a specific position on hovering as following:

```
.menu[data-active-index="0"] > .menu-background-pattern {
  background-position: 0% -25%;
}
```

however, it does not happen. what is wrong with the reference or what is wrong elsewhere? it is clear that the id and the data-active-index are matching. The CSS and JS are in the same folder and the html is in another folder.

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
    const menu = document.getElementById("menu");

    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item"))
        .forEach((item, index) => {
            item.onmouseover = () => {
                menu.dataset.activeIndex = index; // numerates elements top to bottom 0 to (length-1)
                console.log(menu) // <div id="menu" data-active-index="2"></div>
            }
        })

    return (
        <div className="menu">
            <div className="menu-items">
                <a href="/" className="menu-item">stuff</a>
                <a href="/" className="menu-item">stuff</a>
                <a href="/" className="menu-item">stuff</a>
                <a href="/" className="menu-item">stuff</a>
            </div>
                <div className="menu-background-pattern">
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

index.css:

```
.menu-background-pattern {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;

  background-image: radial-gradient(
    rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 9%,
    transparent 9%
    );
    background-position: 0% 0%;
    background-size: 12vmin 12vmin;

    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;

    transition: opacity 800ms ease,
      background-size 800ms ease;
}
```

I pretty much just typed it down from the video, but maybe it is not working because it is a react application it is running inside. The transition of opacity and background-size is also working.

Comment: `.menu[data-active-index="0"]` primarily refers to a class, yet you are using `menu` as an `id`. Either set it as a class on the `div` or use `#menu[data-active-index="0"]` or just `div[data-active-index="0"]` in your css selector. Also be aware that `id` must be unique in a document and most selectors only regard its first occurrence.

Comment: hello, there is no id hardcoded to the menu except for the `className`. this might set the id, but it is not indicated by the docs. 
sadly, using `#menu[data-active-index="0"]` nor using `div[data-active-index="0"]` solved the problem, but thanks for trying anyway!

Comment: also, using the class attribute produces an ugly warning in react since its using react-dom and its not liking `class`

Comment: I have no experience with react, but it looks like you are assigning the event handlers using `document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item")` before you append the elements to the DOM.